# How Do I Determine Row Count of a Structure

Tags: ios, function

I have a structure, elements_table, in my iPhone app.  I'm trying to use the following code to determine the number of rows in the function.  However, when I use my function name, I get an "invalid receiver type" warning.  I'm very new at this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [elements_table count];
}
```

Comment: elements_table should be of array type to return the count. most likely - it isn't right now!

Comment: struct {
 int atomic_number;
 char element_name[15];
 char element_symbol[5];
 int symbol_length;
 int category;
 bool option_used;
} elements_table[2]={
 {1,"Hydrogen", "H", 1, 0, 0},
 {2, "Helium", "He", 2, 0, 0},
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements_table[2] is C struct, not Objective-C, and because of that it cant return [elements_table count]. You can add some variable to store it's count(now it 2, i think).
Or if you don't need strong optimisation, you can use NSArray instead of struct.

Comment: Thanks for info.  I had a C program working with the structure, now I'm trying to make it an i-phone app.  I'm not too familiar with NSArray.  Would I need multiple NSArrays?  Can I have one NSArray holding multiple fields as my structure does (int, char & boolean)?

Comment: @Rick Yes, you can put NSDictionarys in NSArray. Or Implement your class for structure, create objects of it and put them in Array.